# Angular and $injector

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some trouble with one task. In my page some DOM elements added after application has been bootstrapped. I found solution like this

```
var $div = $('<textarea ng-model="questions.question1"></textarea>');
$(document.body).append($div);
angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
  var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
  $compile($div)(scope);
});
```

I can dynamically write unique ng-model for each textarea, but it still not works when I'm trying make console.log($scope.questions.question1) I get - undefined. How can I make this code work?

Comment: Where are you trying the `console.log`?

Comment: In function that invokes when I want to send form data to server. Code example that  I wrote above it is mix of jquery code and angular, because I can't change jquery part but I need data stored in text areas. I need this data but I have no idea how make it work.

Comment: Is the associated controller placed on the body tag or somewhere else?

Comment: I'm using route provider and for page with my form I have a controller and in this controller I have a function that sends data to server. The main problem is to compile this textareas because I have models there but textareas are creating after page has bootstrapped and I don't have access to this models values because I have to send them to server.

Comment: Is ´ng-view` placed on the body tag or on a child element?

Comment: ng-view in the body, but how it affects on code? Do you have a code example to make my models from textarea working after bootstrapping the page?

Comment: Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Vec6bmOwbadxToSi9Ri?p=preview (write in the textboxes to see that it works)